# Why ✓ symbol sometimes gets replaced with âœ“ one?

Tags: html, css, unicode

I've got the following css rule:

```
.icon {
    content: "✓";
    color: #337ab7;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1em;
    margin-left: -1em;
}
```

where I use UTF-8 character ✓. But I've found that sometimes this symbol gets replaced with "âœ“"symbol on a page.

Why it happens?

**[Update]**:

- Chorme browser of 72.0.3626.121 version.
- Header section contains `<meta charset="utf-8">` declaration

**[Update 2]**: I've found that css file responds with the response header:

```
content-encoding: br
```

Comment: Using what browser? Is this inline CSS or in a CSS file? What actual encoding is the parent file using? What does the response look like in a tool like Wireshark?

Comment: I'm using Chrome. This is external CSS file. Response of this file contains broken symbol. Again, this issues appears from time to time.

Comment: Setting `<meta charset="utf8">` doesn't set a the page's encoding, it's just a hint to browsers when the actual encoding used cannot be determined automatically (also, it's `utf-8` not `utf8`). What matters is the actual encoding used by the software that's being used to either save the page's markup or generate it in a web-application.

Comment: I'm using Cloudflare as s CDN. maybe the reason with it

Comment: Maybe I should use  HTML entity ?

Comment: @Dai You understate the importance of `<meta charset="UTF-8">` to the browser. It's not just a hint for when the encoding can't be determined automatically, it is actively used by the browser to determine the encoding when there is no BOM or http header.

Comment: @MrLister No. HTTP header has not much priority. BOM is used mostly by Microsoft (for transition to UTF8 reasons). So meta has priority on other information you listed, but browsers usually use additional heuristics. See HTML5 for details.  -- In any case, we are discussing CSS, so `meta` is not relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with the entity: `content: "\2713";`

Comment: For people asking what this acutally means:
This is the escaped hexadecimal-unicode representation of the icon. By defining the unicode explicitly we are not dependend on the browser knowing the symbol is in UTF-8 when parsing it.

Answer (score 7):

The reason: the character `✓` is U+2713 (Unicode code point), which in UTF-8 is coded as `E2 9C 93`. So I assume your file is correctly coded as UTF-8.

But somehow the file is read as Windows-1252, where `E2` is `â`, `9C` is `œ`, and `93` is `“`. Maybe your server think it is text and advertise the encoding with some obsolete encoding (CSS, and BTW also most web, should be UTF-8 by default).

You may need to add `@charset "utf-8";` at the top of your CSS, to force browsers to interpret the file as UTF-8. See https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-charset for details.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `content: &#10004;` instead of "✓"